# Why does my C program give me weird outputs?

Tags: arrays, c

i am new to C and i was trying to write a code that removes all the duplicate from and array of integers and print the result. But no matter what input i give it returns an output that dosent makes any sense. For example if i give the input 1,1,2,2,3 it gives me the output 1,48 instead of 1,2,3. The output dosen't make any sense. Can anybody please tell me what am i doing wrong. It might be very silly mistake i am not seeing. So irrespective of the input the first duplicate gets removed but the the code prints 48 and exits.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[5],i,j;
    printf("Enter the values of the array\n");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d\n", &arr[i]);
        }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            for(j=i+1;j<5;j++)
                {  
                    if(arr[i]==arr[j])
                        {
                            arr[j] = 0;
                        }
                }
        }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            if(arr[i] > 0)
                    {
                        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
                    }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d\n" ...` --> `scanf("%d" ...`.  Drop the `'\n'`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica tried doing that but still no change :( .

Comment: "1,1,2,2,3" --> do not use commas in input.  Post _exact_ input, _exact_ output.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica tried without the commas and problem solved, huge thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

hey there is nothing wrong in your code.
i have verified in a online compiler and got the expected output.
make sure you give only 5 inputs.
here is what ive checked
**programme:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[5],i,j;
    printf("Enter the values of the array\n");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d\n", &arr[i]);
        }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            for(j=i+1;j<5;j++)
                {  
                    if(arr[i]==arr[j])
                        {
                            arr[j] = 0;
                        }
                }
        }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            if(arr[i] > 0)
                    {
                        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
                    }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**
Enter the values of the array
1 1 2 2 3 5

1 2 3

Comment: "nothing wrong in your code." and 6 inputs `1 1 2 2 3 5` when only should be 5 is a contradiction.